# using PHP to build Time Display from epoch Past time

Tags: php, time, gmt

I store a date in the database of when an action is taken, like downloading a file.

When they need to redownload the file, I want to display the date when they originally downloaded it.

I store that date in mysql, in epoch: php code is time()...

So, when I get that in this field for example:

$pastDateEpoch

here is what I'm trying to build it:

```
  $_filedldate = date("F j, Y g:i a", $pastDateEpoch); // This did works, but is GMT
```

how do I change it to my desired timezone of CST (which is -6 in some places, but I see some say -5), so I don't know which one to do, but is there a way to have it convert it to CST?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

all php scripts use the default timezone. You should take a look at https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-set.php

Your code will look with something like:

```
date_default_timezone_set('America/Los_Angeles');
$_filedldate = date("F j, Y g:i a", $pastDateEpoch);
```

Comment: That worked!!  :) thank you. I did not know that. :) learned something new!!